# Select all from table where user_id exists in both tables

Tags: mysql

I am creating a small chat/ message system. I have four tables: thread, thread_participant, message and message_read_state. I know it might not be the best solution, but I just wanted to give this a go for a project of mine. How can i select all new messages coming in for a specific user without selecting the his/her own message?

### thread table

```
id
----------
1
2
```

### thread_participant table

```
thread_id         user_id
----------        -------- 
1                 6
1                 7
```

### message table

```
id                thread_id    send_date    message     sending_user_id
----------        --------     --------     --------    --------
1                 1            2016-05-12   HELLO       7 
2                 1            2016-05-12   HELLO BACK  6
```

### message_read_state

```
message_id   user_id s    read_date    
-----        --------     --------   
1            6            2016-05-12  
2            7            2016-05-12
```

### EDIT

What I have so far. This select all the threads I have participated, but I would like to display only the incoming message, without my response.

```
SELECT message.id, message.send_date, message.message, tbl_users.user_id, message.thread_id
, (SELECT message_read_state.read_date 
   FROM message_read_state 
   WHERE message_read_state.message_id = message.id 
     and message_read_state.user_id = 6) AS ReadState
FROM message INNER JOIN tbl_users ON message.sending_user_id = tbl_users.user_id
WHERE ( message.id in 
        ( SELECT (message.id)
          FROM thread_participant INNER JOIN message 
            ON thread_participant.thread_id = message.thread_id
          WHERE thread_participant.user_id = 6
          GROUP BY thread_participant.user_id
        )
      )
ORDER BY message.send_date ASC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this;)

```
SELECT message.id, message.send_date, message.message, tbl_users.user_id, message.thread_id
, (SELECT message_read_state.read_date 
   FROM message_read_state 
   WHERE message_read_state.message_id = message.id 
     and message_read_state.user_id = 6) AS ReadState
FROM message INNER JOIN tbl_users ON message.sending_user_id = tbl_users.user_id
WHERE ( message.id in 
        ( SELECT (message.id)
          FROM thread_participant INNER JOIN message 
            ON thread_participant.thread_id = message.thread_id
          WHERE thread_participant.user_id = 6
          GROUP BY thread_participant.user_id
        )
      )
AND message.sending_user_id <> 6
ORDER BY message.send_date ASC;
```

I've just add `AND message.sending_user_id <> 6` in your original sql. If you don't want response, just let `sending_user_id` is not you, then you get what you want. :D

Comment: IT WORKS! man you explain what did you change or how is it working? Would like to know.